# New bug in glmmADMB? VarCorr can't locate rdig

Tags: r, mixed-models

I think this is a newly introduced bug.  At the very least, it bugged previously working code.

```
library(glmmADMB)
epil2$subject <- factor(epil2$subject)
fm <- glmmadmb(y~Base*trt+Age+Visit+(Visit|subject),
            data=epil2, family="nbinom")
VarCorr(fm)
```

Produces the following error:

```
Error in glmmADMB::VarCorr(fm) : 
  could not find symbol "rdig" in environment of the generic function
```

`VarCorr` from `nlme` still works fine:

```
library(nlme)
nlme::VarCorr(fm) ##WORKS
glmmADMB::VarCorr(fm) ##Still doesn't work.
```

Here is my systemInfo if that helps:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nlme_3.1-125   glmmADMB_0.8.1 MASS_7.3-45   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Matrix_1.2-3    plyr_1.8.3      magrittr_1.5    tools_3.2.3    
 [5] coda_0.18-1     Rcpp_0.12.3     stringi_1.0-1   grid_3.2.3     
 [9] stringr_1.0.0   R2admb_0.7.13   lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: It could be related to the update of `VarCorr` in *nlme* that is discussed [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/347).

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to my problem.  I used the installation code provided here:
http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/ .  I am not sure if it was necessary but before running the below code I navigated to my `~R/R-3.2.3/library` folder and deleted the glmmADMB folder.

Then I ran the code below.

```
install.packages("R2admb")
install.packages("glmmADMB", 
    repos=c("http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
            getOption("repos")),
    type="source")
```

This updated my glmmADMB to version 0.8.3.3 which corrected the error (by turning it into a warning).